# How to reference dynamic TypeScript properties within an interface?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to type a theme object which will be used with Tailwind, what I am trying to achieve is dynamically provide typings in the theme signature:

```js
export interface Theme {
  screens: {
    [key: string]: string;
  };
  bps: keyof this['screens'][]; // breakpoints
};
```

What I am trying to achieve is providing an interface to configure the theme but the compiler keeps complaining. Ideally, the implementation of the interface would be as follows:

```js
// good example
const t: Theme = {
    screens: {
        sm: "200px",
        md: "400px"
    },
    bps:["md"] // md exists in screens
}

// bad example
const tt: Theme = {
    screens: {
        sm: "200px",
        md: "400px"
    },
    bps:["foo"] // foo is not a key of screens
}
```

Comment: Does it need to be an `interface`, specifically (so you can do declaration merging), or is a `type` alias sufficient?

Comment: Hi @T.J.Crowder, definitely not. I was just trying to play around with a solution.

Comment: It ends up not mattering. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the only way to do this is to make `Theme` generic so we can infer the types of the keys, and to avoid having to specify that type explicitly, we have to use a do-nothing function when creating the themes.

That looks like this:

```typescript
export interface Theme<Screens extends Record<string, string>> {
    screens: Screens;
    bps: (keyof Screens)[]; // breakpoints
}

function buildTheme<Screens extends Record<string, string>>(
    theme: Theme<Screens>
) {
    return theme;
}

// good example
const t = buildTheme({
    screens: {
        sm: "200px",
        md: "400px",
    },
    bps: ["md"], // Okay
});

// bad example
const tt = buildTheme({
    screens: {
        sm: "200px",
        md: "400px",
    },
    bps: ["foo"], // Error as desired:
    //    ^^^^^−−−−−Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type '"sm" | "md"'.ts(2322)
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgFQAtgBbYAHgGVsphgkBnOUVJAEyYCVhto3yGMKMgDmAGjiDhSEQD5ZcAN4AoOGsk06jAFxxqtegwDcq9QCMwDXQAoA1sACeEdHs2GAlAG0AukbgB6fzgzWkxbSGQYBmUAX2VldABXJGwYBAgkYMSEABs2IlIKfS0mFnoOOG5eKH4pUQk6mXlrUzUYYjJdArIqN0ZZZXclVrhaGESoTPbCkzjlQLgRCAg2ZhBMEjAc4GVeRnh4AF4s3PyO4GsVdQ0DHWHr64YSXQAiACYABg+wEBexEeuJDYrwALF8fn8RjF-tcLFY4J4XkCXt4JAsAPK2TAOWLuEzzIJmTCrUAbLY7PaCOAwI4nPLdC5XdQMPrwpkPSTPODvcG-GEcuBA0G8yHXaEjOG6RHoZYotFBACiUCg0DgmCYbGADAQtGBIwW6gAesbjYAkInN5vwDjAeAA5C8ZRAXrbEEwkBB4OrtSIkJgzNtqRBqda7S8ni84AAfbnI20AOii1jeAGY3m93LijEA)